# sqlite update the table with regex

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 table:

```
id    gross
1     $3,246,771 (USA) (12 April 1987),$3,189,948 (USA) (5 April 1987),$3,110,003 (USA)
2     $3,478 (USA) (3 August 1997),$3,344,136 (USA)
3     € 14,134 (Spain)
4     $3,150,000 (worldwide)
```

I want to extract the data that has USA gross information like this:

```
id    gross
1     3246771
2     3478
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you just trying to capture the very first dollar amount in a line and ignore the others?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, you want to grab the ID number, and then the first comma-separated number in the second column. Correct?

Either way, that should be easy with `re`. Let's assume your data is in a file-like object called `data`.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+).+([0-9](?:,[0-9)+)*)')

print('id\tgross')
for line in data:
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match:
        id, gross = match.groups()
        gross = gross.replace(',', '')
        print('{id}\t{gross}'.format(id=id, gross=float(gross))
```

[Try the regular expression out](https://regex101.com/r/WrdnTX/1).